# Bootstrap 3 push/pull and accessibility

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, accessibility, tabindex, wcag

I'm trying to make our webpages more accessible and am confused about the tab order for push/pull sections.

Here is an example:

```html
<section class="section">
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <a href="#" aria-label="Lorem ipsum" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/770x560" alt="Image" /></a>                    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus</p>
            <div class="btn">
               <a href="#" role="button" tabindex="0" target="_blank">Lorem ipsum</a>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
           <a href="#" aria-label="Lorem ipsum" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/770x560" alt="Image" /></a>         
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus</p>
            <div class="btn">
               <a href="#" role="button" tabindex="0" target="_blank">Lorem ipsum</a>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

When I tab through the row with push/pull, the image is focused first, and the button focused second even though it's displayed on desktop as button first and image second. I understand why it does this, but is this best practice for accessibility? Seems like it'd be confusing for the user. And if this is not best practice, how would I reverse the tab order? Would I need to go through the entire webpage and set `tabindex="0", "1", "2"`, etc. for every focusable element?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using push and pull (i.e. desktop version vs mobile version)? If so [this answer i gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64238701/2702894) has a method for having alternative layouts without having to resort to `tabindex` etc. If that isn't the case a bit more info on why you are doing this will help us give you a thorough solution as DOM order is key for accessibility.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I tried to keep the code as short as possible to make things easier, but I probably stripped out too much. I added another row that doesn't contain the push/pull. Basically we just wanted the aesthetic of having alternating image/text and CTA on desktop but have them stack image first and text and CTA second on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Q is a little general.

**Accessibility concerns:**

> Avoid using tabindex values greater than 0. Doing so makes it
> difficult for people who rely on assistive technology to navigate and
> operate page content. Instead, write the document with the elements in
> a logical sequence.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex#Accessibility_concerns

#### `Interactive_content` (interactive focusable by keyboard)

Some HTML elements are focusable by default (buttons/links/Form inputs, and so on).

The tab order of this

```html
 <a href="#" tabindex="0">First in tab order</a>
 <a href="#" tabindex="0">Second in tab order</a>
```

Is the same as this (Without `tabindex="0"`):

```html
 <a href="#">First in tab order</a></div> | 
 <a href="#">Second in tab order</a></div>
```

#### "The answer to this Q:

**"Would I need to go through the entire webpage and set tabindex="0", "1", "2""**

`NO`.

> If multiple elements share the same positive tabindex value, their
> order relative to each other follows their position in the document
> source [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

`document source` = Change the order by CSS `flexbox`, `grid`, and so on will **not** affect the tab order. So assistive technology navigate throw your content in the **correct** order.

Flexbox `order` Example:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item:nth-of-type(1) { order: 3; }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(2) { order: 4; }
.flex-item:nth-of-type(3) { order: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"><button>Tab order 1</button></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><button>Tab order 2</button></div>
  <div class="flex-item"><button>Tab order 3</button></div>
</div>
```

In the example below the `div` is Tabbable due to tabindex.

```html
<label>First in tab order:<input type="text"></label>
<br>
<a href="#">Second in tab order</a> 
<div tabindex="0"><b>Tabbable</b> due to tabindex.</div>
<label>Third in tab order:<input type="text"></label>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and for clarifying some things about accessibility I was fuzzy on. I made a small tweak to your solution and it worked for my purpose. I removed the push/pull classes and set it up in the order it's supposed to be for desktop. Inside a media query I had: .flex-container {
    display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
This way I didn't need to set up the flex-items.